# Fade In and / or Out Placeholder Text

Tags: jquery, fade, placeholder

Is there a way to fade in and out an input's placeholder text?

I've tried:

```
$('.userBox::-webkit-input-placeholder').animate({color: '#888888'}, 500);
```

But this just crashes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to fade out on focus, and fade back in on blur (*when the input box is empty*), the following should work in webkit:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="user@example.org" type="email" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="email"]::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; 
  color: gray;
}

input[type="email"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9UA3/

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the placeholder text supplied by the browsers' implementation, I don't believe so. if you wanted to implement a custom placeholder using `focus`, `blur` & `key*` events then yes it's possible.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
$('.userBox::-webkit-input-placeholder').fadeOut(500);
```

Or, alternatively you could use [this](http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this fades out the entire text box

Comment: @Isaac plugin will do nothing on browser which support natively placeholder attribute

Comment: @roasted But for older browsers it will show the place holder

Comment: @Isaac anyway i don't think this will help OP in what he's looking for