# Using jQuery to animate an input tag's placeholder attribute

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm surprised this has not been asked before.

The purpose is purely aesthetic and will not affect UX.

Is it possible to use jQuery `.animate()`, `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()`, etc. with the value contained in an `<input>` tag's `placeholder` attribute?

Example:

```
<input name="user" placeholder="Please enter your username" />
```

When the input field is clicked, the placeholder text fades out. If the user clicks out and the field loses focus, the placeholder text fades back in.

Comment: Ask before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625737/fade-in-and-or-out-placeholder-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fade In and / or Out Placeholder Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625737/fade-in-and-or-out-placeholder-text)

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#textbox1').on("focus",function(){
    $('#textbox1').attr('placeholder').fadeOut();
  });
  $('#textbox1').on("blur",function(){
    $('#textbox1').attr('placeholder').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: You might want to test your code before you put it in an answer. I made a [JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/g7vZ7/) that shows you it unfortunately doesn't work.